# Function is Closed?

Tags: closed-map

While reading the optimization textbook, the below proposition given:

**Let $f: X \mapsto [-\infty, \infty]$ be a function. If $ \text{dom}(f)$ is closed and $f$ is lower semicontinuous at each x$\in \text{dom}(f)$, then $f$ is closed.**

dom($f$) refers to the effective domain of f where $f(x) < \infty$ $\forall x \in$ dom($f$)

What is the closed of functions?

---

Miscellaneous question:

When denoting function, {domain $\to$ codomain} is different from {domain $\mapsto$ codomain}?

Because this textbook never uses the former one but later ones only.

Comment: The two different arrow symbols $\to$ and $\mapsto$ should mean the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be two competing definitions of "closed" with respect to functions:

(i) This page defines a closed map as one that maps closed sets to closed sets (but that definition would not make your theorem true, so that is likely *not* the correct definition in this context):

http://mathonline.wikidot.com/open-and-closed-maps-on-topological-spaces

To see how this definition fails your theorem, consider the counter-example lower-semicontinuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by:

$$ f(x)= \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0&\mbox{ if $x \leq 0$} \\
x+1  & \mbox{ if $x>0$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
then consider the closed set $[0,1]$ and its mapped set $f([0,1])$.

(ii) This page defines a closed function as one such that, for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{x \in dom(f): f(x) \leq \alpha\}$ is closed.  This is *not equivalent* to the first definition, yet, it makes your theorem true.  So it must be the correct definition in this context.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_convex_function

It is remarkable (and annoying) that your textbook does not bother to define "closed function."

Comment: the second one is just perfectly fit to the context I think. Thanks for your great elaboration.